# IPTables: How to log and set a specific log file

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, logging, debian-jessie

Is it possible log all dropped connections by IPTables and set a iptables.log file for logging in /var/log/?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this my configuring iptables to 'mark' the messages e.g.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j LOG --log-prefix='[iptables] '
```

Which will cause a log message that is prefixed with the text `[iptables]`

Now you can configure your rsyslog to send these messages to a particular log file by adding a suitable entry to it's configuration e.g.

```
:msg,contains,"[iptables] " /var/log/iptables.log
```

Comment: This will cause messages to go to both syslog and iptables.log. To prevent them from going to syslog, add another line :msg,contains "[iptables] " ~ (that's a tilde). I added these rules to /etc/rsyslog.d/10-iptables.conf. Also, /var/log/iptables.log must exist and be chown'd to syslog:adm.

Answer (score -1):

there is a way to log packets in IPTables. first you need to create new chain to logging packets.

```
iptables -N LOGGING
```

then you need to append which packets you are gonna log using following commands.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
```

now you can log the packets to the syslogs using this.

```
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
```

finally this command.

```
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

please add this new lines to bottom of your IPTables files.

Comment: But where will it be logged? Where can I find the log file?

Comment: They are logged in kern.log by default. but you can change this in your syslog server configuration.

Comment: Does not answer the question, which is to log to a separate file.